# Jupyter Notebook stopped running with "Uncaught Exception Get..."

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook stopped running. Please help...

I was running Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda 3 on an Intel Mac and suddenly today the Jupyter Notebook could not run any command.
It would get stuck at [*] for a long time then would return nothing. No error message, no result.

On the terminal, red error message reads: Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/dcf5548f-bc04-4adb-b704-55cf280d3473/channels?session_id=ddec49e27a7f48289015fc865b954997 (::1)....

I ran 'conda update' --all successfully.
I assume everything is up to date but the problem persisted.
BTW, when I click update in Anaconda Navigator, the installer would get stuck at "updating root package" forever, and I had to quit.

Not sure if this was related to my jupyter notebook problem.

Comment: according to https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/462

you should be able to run

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade notebook` to resolve this

Comment: running "python3 -m pip install --upgrade notebook" results the error message:"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for upgrade"